# Identityserver4, problem with running and implementation

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, identityserver4

I want to create a centralize asp.net core API project with Entity-FrameWork core for membership management such as login, register and etc. and Separately I want to create another asp.net core project and use centralized project for membership like google.com.
After a lot of search, i understood that should use IdentityServer4. I read this document and got sample from Github, but it was not clear and I was confused.
Who can explain clearly and step by step?
thank you

Comment: which document?

Comment: here : http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/index.html

Comment: What are you confused about exactly? What problems are you experiencing? What is not working as it should? Do you get any exceptions? If so, what are those? We need much more information here to give you an answer.

Comment: I don't know what is the scenario. I just want two project that one of them is login/register api and another join it to login or register. what is the configuration of second project? Do you have any complete sample for my request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IdentityServer4 has simple MeadleWare for use in Asp.Net Core

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
   ...
   var cert = new X509Certificate2("/Cert/cert.pfx", "123456");

   services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApisResources())
                .AddSigningCredential(cert)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .Services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
   ...
}

public void Configure(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env){
   ...
   app.UseIdentityServer();
   ...
}
```

and create a config file:

```
public class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApisResources()
        {
            return new[]
            {
                // simple API with a single scope (in this case the scope name is the same as the api name)
                new ApiResource("api1"),
            };
        }


        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "spa",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
                //IdentityTokenLifetime=10,

                AllowOfflineAccess=true,
                RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
                AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 999999,
                RefreshTokenUsage=TokenUsage.ReUse,
                AccessTokenType=AccessTokenType.Jwt,

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    "api1",
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess
                },
                AccessTokenLifetime=36000
            }
        };
        }
    }
```

then in resourceServer use Bellow MW:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
   ...
   services.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                o.Audience = "self";
                o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    RequireExpirationTime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };

                o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
                    {
                        c.NoResult();
                        c.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        c.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                        return c.Response.WriteAsync(c.Exception.ToString());
                    },
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnChallenge = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
   ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   {
      ...
      app.UseAuthentication();
      ...
   }
```

Comment: Thank you. This codes should be used in login/register project? How can use this identityserver4 in login/register project in another projects and services?